# XOR performance improvement via instrinics?

Tags: c, performance, assembly, cryptography, aes

I have some code where I step through two buffers and XOR one against the placing the results in a third. Specifically, this is a buffer of data, a key stream buffer, and a destination buffer.

The function in question is (in full)

```
static int
ssh_aes_ctr(EVP_CIPHER_CTX *ctx, u_char *dest, const u_char *src,
    LIBCRYPTO_EVP_INL_TYPE len)
{
        typedef union {
#ifdef CIPHER_INT128_OK
                __uint128_t *u128;
#endif
                uint64_t *u64;
                uint32_t *u32;
                uint8_t *u8;
                const uint8_t *cu8;
                uintptr_t u;
        } ptrs_t;
        ptrs_t destp, srcp, bufp;
        uintptr_t align;
        struct ssh_aes_ctr_ctx_mt *c;
        struct kq *q, *oldq;
        int ridx;
        u_char *buf;

        if (len == 0)
                return 1;
        if ((c = EVP_CIPHER_CTX_get_app_data(ctx)) == NULL)
                return 0;

        q = &c->q[c->qidx];
        ridx = c->ridx;

        /* src already padded to block multiple */
        srcp.cu8 = src;
        destp.u8 = dest;
        do { /* do until len is 0 */
                buf = q->keys[ridx];
                bufp.u8 = buf;

                /* figure out the alignment on the fly */
#ifdef CIPHER_UNALIGNED_OK
                align = 0;
#else
                align = destp.u | srcp.u | bufp.u;
#endif

                /* xor the src against the key (buf)
                 * different systems can do all 16 bytes at once or
                 * may need to do it in 8 or 4 bytes chunks
                 * worst case is doing it as a loop */
#ifdef CIPHER_INT128_OK
                if ((align & 0xf) == 0) {
                        destp.u128[0] = srcp.u128[0] ^ bufp.u128[0];
                } else
#endif
                /* 64 bits */
                if ((align & 0x7) == 0) {
                        destp.u64[0] = srcp.u64[0] ^ bufp.u64[0];
                        destp.u64[1] = srcp.u64[1] ^ bufp.u64[1];
                /* 32 bits */
                } else if ((align & 0x3) == 0) {
                        destp.u32[0] = srcp.u32[0] ^ bufp.u32[0];
                        destp.u32[1] = srcp.u32[1] ^ bufp.u32[1];
                        destp.u32[2] = srcp.u32[2] ^ bufp.u32[2];
                        destp.u32[3] = srcp.u32[3] ^ bufp.u32[3];
                } else {
                        /*1 byte at a time*/
                        size_t i;
                        for (i = 0; i < AES_BLOCK_SIZE; ++i)
                                dest[i] = src[i] ^ buf[i];
                }

                /* inc/decrement the pointers by the block size (16)*/
                destp.u += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;
                srcp.u += AES_BLOCK_SIZE;

                /* Increment read index, switch queues on rollover */
                if ((ridx = (ridx + 1) % KQLEN) == 0) {
                        oldq = q;
                        /* Mark next queue draining, may need to wait */
                        c->qidx = (c->qidx + 1) % numkq;
                        q = &c->q[c->qidx];
                        pthread_mutex_lock(&q->lock);
                        while (q->qstate != KQFULL) {
                                pthread_cond_wait(&q->cond, &q->lock);
                        }
                        q->qstate = KQDRAINING;
                        pthread_cond_broadcast(&q->cond);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&q->lock);

                        /* Mark consumed queue empty and signal producers */
                        pthread_mutex_lock(&oldq->lock);
                        oldq->qstate = KQEMPTY;
                        pthread_cond_broadcast(&oldq->cond);
                        pthread_mutex_unlock(&oldq->lock);
                }
        } while (len -= AES_BLOCK_SIZE);
        c->ridx = ridx;
        return 1;
}
```

Running this through vtune I find that the `destp.u128[0] = srcp.u128[0] ^ bufp.u128[0];` line consumes 4% of the cpu time.

The assembly for this line is

```
shl $0x4, %rax
addq (%rsp), %rax
movq (%rax), %rdx
xorq (%rbx), %rdx
movq 0x8(%rax), %rax
xorq 0x8(%rax), %rax
movq %rax, 0x8(%r12)
```

The `xorq (%rbx), %rdx` is consuming 3.5% of the CPU time. What I am wondering is if I could improve performance by vectorizing the data being xor'd and then using intrinsics to perform the xor. I don't have much (read any) real experience in using intrinsics but I'm willing to learn. I just don't know if this code, as is, is about as good as I can expect. Any pointers would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: This kind of algorithms are usually memory bound. Consider memcpy as an upper bound of performance that you can get. Try to compare your code with memcpy to see how much you can squeeze from further optimizations

Comment: Have you checked whether all of the gnarly undefined behavior in accessing your buffers in various sizes *actually* improves performance? Does it *still* improve performance if you allow the compiler to optimize it? *Even if you allow the compiler to use a reasonably modern CPU generation as a target*? Because `gcc` and `clang` [will](https://godbolt.org/z/M5G1hKce9) happily vectorize `xor` over a char buffer.

Comment: @EOF This was checked when the code was originally written some 12 years ago or so. I don't have the performance documents from then and I am not sure they'd be applicable any more. That said, we were doing that so we don't have to do a byte by byte xoring on platforms that support alternatives. That said, I can check to see if I can the entire buffer up to 'len' in one go. I think that's what you are suggesting. Please let me know if that isn't correct. 

That said, I haven't seen any implementation of AES do more than AES_BLOCK_SIZE (16B) in one go.

Comment: Note that mainstream x86-64 processors have a dedicated instruction to compute AES very efficiently. In fact, x86-64 ones are not the only one. Please read: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AES_instruction_set . Beside this, the alignment conditions in the loop are not needed: I think you can move them away from the loop (and replicate the whole loop) assuming `AES_BLOCK_SIZE` is a power of two >= 16.

Comment: @JérômeRichard Yup. I know about those. This code is a threaded implementation of AESCTR in which the keystream is precomputed. I use OpenSSL's EVP API so that directly calls the AESNI on die methods if they are supported by the CPU. Computing the keystream is the expensive part so having a few threads works on that while the main thread handles everything else works pretty well. Depends on the CPU but up to 25% faster with better performance on more CPU bound systems. 

This chunk of code is from HPNSSH which is at https://github.com/rapier1/openssh-portable if you are interested.

Comment: Interesting, according to a combination of [the gcc release history](https://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html) and available gcc versions on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Gvsznrz7E), gcc would not have autovectorized the obvious code in 2007, but it definitely would have in 2012, so 12 years ago might theoretically *just barely* be long enough ago that the "optimizations" used in this code would not have been cargoculting back then (though this is almost certainly not actually true, because there is a large gap in the ancient gcc versions on godbolt). They definitely are now.

Comment: @EOF so basically, I can get rid of the struct and methods that currently do the alignments and let the compiler figure that out? My concern is that might impact portability of the binary (as this is released as a package) but I can work around that. I'll give that a go and see if it has an impact on performance.

Comment: If you're worried about "portability" to other reasonable compilers, the oldest `clang` version on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/c5W79qoKT) that vectorizes this seems to be 3.3 (released 2013?). If you're [worried](https://godbolt.org/z/5P8rP316c) [about](https://godbolt.org/z/1176MTqh3) [other](https://godbolt.org/z/cGTh5rdEc) processor architectures, don't. If it has a reasonable vector unit, decent compilers will do better than you could.